# Open word documents from excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I try to look for the solution of this issue, but I could not figure out. I really appreciate the help

From my excel : cell A1 = "appendix1", cell A2 = "appendix2"; cell A3 = "appendix4"; cell A4 = "appendix1"; cell A5 = "appendix1"
I have a folder with the following document: appendix1.docx; appendix2.docx; appendix3.docx; appendix4.docx; appendix5.docx
I am looking for a code that help me open the appendix documents from the cells in excel; each appendix should appear one time

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test111()
Dim wApp As New Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim fName As String

For i = 1 To 5
fName = Cells(i, 1)
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(fName & ".docx")
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: for wApp.Documents.Open(fName & “.docx”). Does excel and word documents need to be in the same folder?

Comment: you can add a path to fName variable. By default it picks from the activefolder name. What folder is active at the moment - depends on what file code is acting with